# How to write test cases for titanium with alloy

Tags: mocha.js, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I am stuck while writing test cases for alloy framework as i am not getting how to use controllers and alloy files in mocha testing framework. I searched on google and few links suggested below code to moke a controller but it throws error that  "TypeError: alloy.createController is not a function".

var alloy = require('../../alloy');
it('Verify row controller', function() {

```
        console.log(JSON.stringify(alloy))
        var controller = alloy.createController('login', {
            name : "uniqueName",
        });

        // if(controller.passwordTest.value !== "uniqueName"){
        // throw new ("Verify row controller FAILED");
        // }
    });
```

Comment: Does your controller requires other libraries? I can already show you an example if no other libraries are required. Actually we are currently working on better unit test support for Titanium applications though the code is not finished yet. Once we have everything in place we will open-source it.

Comment: our controller is not dependent on others, if you can show please show a project where i can see running alloy code for test cases.

Comment: When i am running the grunt command it is showing some error. please take a look and suggest what i am forgetting to make it run.

pankaj-mac:HDReorderApp ankit.pal$ grunt


Running "test-env" task

Running "alloy:should_new" (alloy) task


/Users/ankit.pal/Documents/Appc/HDReorderApp/node_modules/.bin/alloy new --noBanner --logLevel 1 


/Users/ankit.pal/Documents/Appc/HDReorderApp/tmp/grunt-alloy-app

**Fatal error: spawn /Users/ankit.pal/Documents/Appc/HDReorderApp/node_modules/.bin/alloy ENOENT.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I can show you a (slightly modified) example of our codebase.

First of all, our controller tests are pure javascript tests. All calls to the Ti api are executed against a mock. We solely focus on the controller under test and all dependencies are mocked.

We rely on jasmine and jasmine-npm for that.

- install jasmine-npm; see https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm
- create 'spec' folder in the root of your project (folder with tiapp.xml)
- place all your test files inside this folder
- the filenames of test files must end with _spec.js
- run the jasmine command from within the root folder of your project

  describe('authenticate controller test', function() {

  ```
  var USER_NAME = "John Doe";

  var fooControllerMock = {
      getView: function(){}
  };

  var fooViewMock = {
      open: function(){}
  }


  Ti = {
      // create here a mock for all Ti* functions and properties you invoke in your controller
  }

  Alloy = {
      CFG: {
          timeout: 100
      },
      Globals: {
          loading: {
              hide: function(){}
          },
          networkClient: {
              hasAutoLogin: function(){}
          },
          notifications: {
              showError: function(){}
          }
      },
      createController: function(){}
  };

  var controllerUnderTest; // class under test

  $ = {
      btnAuthenticate: {
          addEventListener: function(){}
      },
      authenticate: {
          addEventListener: function(){},
          close: function(){}
      },
      username: {
          addEventListener: function(){},
          getValue: function(){}
      },
      password: {
          addEventListener: function(){}
      },
      windowContainer: {
          addEventListener: function(){}
      }
  };

  L = function(s){
      return s;
  };

  beforeEach(function () {
      controllerUnderTest = require('../app/controllers/auth');
  });



  it('should create foo controller when authentication was succesful', function(){
      spyOn(Alloy.Globals.loading, 'hide');
      spyOn(Alloy, 'createController').and.returnValue(fooControllerMock);
      spyOn(fooControllerMock, 'getView').and.returnValue(fooViewMock);
      spyOn($.username, 'getValue').and.returnValue(USER_NAME);
      spyOn($.auth, 'close');

      controllerUnderTest.test._onAuthSuccess();

      expect(Alloy.Globals.loading.hide).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(Alloy.createController).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo');
      expect(fooControllerMock.getView).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect($.auth.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should show error message when a login error has occured', function(){
      spyOn(Alloy.Globals.loading, 'hide');
      spyOn(Alloy.Globals.notifications, 'showError');

      controllerUnderTest.test._onAuthLoginError();

      expect(Alloy.Globals.loading.hide).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(Alloy.Globals.notifications.showError).toHaveBeenCalledWith('msg.auth.failure');
  });

  });
  ```

Be sure to write a mock implementation(just empty) for all Ti* stuff you call from within your controller. I know this is quite cumbersome but a solution is on it's way.

Note that we already created an npm package which has a generated mock for this (based on api.jsca), together with some code with which you can mock all required dependencies, together with a set of testing best practices. However we will validate this code internally before we opensource it. I hope we can write our blog post and expose our accompanying github repo within a few weeks. Just keep an eye on tiSlack.

Controller code:

```
function _onAuthSuccess() {
    Alloy.Globals.loading.hide();
    Alloy.createController('foo').getView().open();
    $.authenticate.close();
}

function _onAuthLoginError() {
    Alloy.Globals.loading.hide();
    Alloy.Globals.notifications.showError(L('msg.auth.failure'));
}

function _onAuthTokenValidationFailure() {
    Alloy.Globals.loading.hide();
}

function _authenticate() {
    var username = $.username.value;
    var password = $.password.value;

    if(Alloy.Globals.validationEmail.isValidEmailAddress(username)){
        Alloy.Globals.loading.show(L('authenticate.msg.logging.in'), false);
    } else {
        Alloy.Globals.notifications.showError(L('app.error.invalid.email'));
    }
}

function _onNetworkAbsent() {
    Alloy.Globals.loading.hide();
    Alloy.Globals.notifications.showError(L('global.no.network.connection.available'));
}

function _hideKeyboard() {
    $.username.blur();
    $.password.blur();
}

function _focusPassword() {
    $.username.blur();
    $.password.focus();
}

function _init() {
    Ti.App.addEventListener('auth:success', _onAuthSuccess);
    Ti.App.addEventListener('auth:loginFailed', _onAuthLoginError);
    Ti.App.addEventListener('app:parseError', _onAppParseError);
    Ti.App.addEventListener('network:none', _onNetworkAbsent);

    $.btnAuthenticate.addEventListener('click', ..);
    $.authenticate.addEventListener('close', _cleanup);
    $.username.addEventListener('return', _focusPassword);
    $.password.addEventListener('return', _authenticate);

    $.windowContainer.addEventListener('touchstart', _hideKeyboard);
}

_init();

function _cleanup() {
    Ti.API.info('Closing and destroying the auth controller');
     ... 
    $.windowContainer.removeEventListener('touchstart', _hideKeyboard);

    $.destroy();
    $.off();
    }

    module.exports = {
    test: {
        _onAuthSuccess: _onAuthSuccess,
        _onAuthLoginError: _onAuthLoginError
        }
    }
```

and the corresponding view:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window>
        <View id="windowContainer">
            <TextField id="username" />
            <TextField id="password" >
            <Button id="btnAuthenticate" />               
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Comment: Can you please share the authentication file as well?

that will help me to understand the concept.

Comment: for code coverage we are using jasmine-node together with istanbul (without karma). This combination works the best for us, it is easy to set up and it plays well if you require node_module stuff while bootstrapping unit tests.  Our approach is based on https://bryce.fisher-fleig.org/blog/setting-up-istanbul-with-jasmine/. I hope to write a blog post about it very soon

Comment: beforeEach(function () {
    controllerUnderTest = require('../app/controllers/auth');
});

your controller name is auth?

Comment: we are using ti-mocha any idea about this.

How can we write test cases for this and what we can use for code coverage.

Comment: controller name is 'auth' indeed. No idea about how to combine it with ti-mocha

Comment: One more question... For titanium do we use some other jasmine library or it is same as we are using for angularjs projects.

Comment: we are using the same jasmine library

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, i will try to implement jasmine in our project. if i face any issue while doing this, i will post a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium internally uses [Ti-Mocha](https://github.com/tonylukasavage/ti-mocha) to write unit-tests for all of it's components. It's a modified version of [Mocha](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha) and uses test-suites, test-cases, chaining and much more to test suitable code-coverage. Give it a try!

Comment: Hans, correct me if I am wrong, but this still requires the Titanium runtime, isn't it? Is it capable of mocking calls to eg. Ti.Network.getNetworkType or do you need to alter your runtime environment in any way to switch between 3G and Edge in your tests?

Comment: Hey David, yes that is correct. But in order to test the controllers logic properly, this should be seen as a necessary step. I wrote a test-suite for one of my example applications this year, please check https://github.com/hansemannn/hyperloop-robot/blob/master/app/lib/tests/suites.js on how it can work. Thx!

Comment: Can you please provide any example for mocking a http call?

Comment: Sure, check this example: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium-mobile-mocha-suite/blob/master/Resources/ti.network.httpclient.test.js#L221